# How can I echo last query in cakephp 1.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, cakephp, echo

I'm new to cakephp and having trouble in echo the last query. I want to see what is my sql query that is being executed coz it's not returning the expected result. The version of cakephp is 1.2.6. 
I have tried the following code

```
//$log = $this->Auction->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); ( this does not work,  maybe due to old version )
$log =  $this->Auction->getDataSource()->showLog( false );

//debug($this->Auction->lastQuery()); ( same goes for this line. lastQuery is not working maybe due to old version) 

debug( $log );
```

This line shows

> ```
> (default) 0 query took ms
> Nr Query  Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
> public_html/controllers/auctions_controller.php (line 416)
>
> (default) 0 query took ms
> Nr    Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
> ```

But what i want is the sql query to view.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 1.x, the data you want is accessible in `DataSource::_queriesLog.`

```
$dbo = $this->getDatasource();
$logs = $dbo->_queriesLog;

return end($logs);
```

Comment: return end($logs) was giving me an array of a lot of data  so I changed your code a bit. 
echo "<pre">;print_r($logs);die;

but it gives 
(default) 0 query took ms
Nr Query Error Affected Num. rows Took (ms)
Array
(
)
(default) 0 query took ms
Nr Query Error Affected Num. rows Took (ms)